# TorCtl connection refused error

Tags: python, tor

While browsing about changing identity with tor I have the following script:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl

conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")

TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
```

But I get this error:

```
Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_tor.py", line 18, in <module>
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
TypeError: unbound method send_signal() must be called with Connection instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)
```

And What shoul be the passphrase? I have tried without passphrase the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do

```
conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
```

You could try printing conn in between the calls. See if it's None. Maybe the connection failed.

Comment: Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_tor.py", line 18, in <module>
    conn.send("NEWNYM")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: @user873286 So the connection is indeed refused. Are you sure that tor is listening at 127.0.0.1 in that port and that pass? Can you check netstat -l and also see if there is any mention of the connection attempt in tor's logs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at vivaldia settings, in the advanced tab, look at the address and the port number below controlport, it may be 9151 instead of 9050. Then set another password (uncheck the box random password).